# Windows 10 wierd hiddin filenames

Tags: windows, windows-10, filenames

Anyone knows why this bugs occur? It's across the whole system, not just Handbrake

[image]

Comment: Your filename is too long or your folders are nested too deeply by the looks of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see the 8.3 alias (known as short filename) of the long name. It is not a bug, it is a filesystem backward compatibility function.

You can see it on Your station too. Open CMD console and study the output of the command

```
C:\> DIR /X
```

You can see both short (8.3) and long filenames in it (if short filenames support is not disabled in Your OS, of course).

The problem You show can have a lot of reasons. It can occur, for example, when full pathname (`\\server\share\folder\folder\filename.extension`) is too long (afaik Windows Explorer has 254-symbols limitation for the full pathname), and 8.3 aliases support is disabled on the remote station.

Comment: Thanks, That seems to be the problem.By moving the files to my desktop, nothing problematic occured